# Javascript email encryption, am I doing this right?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I came up with a way to encrypt email addresses using javascript, but seeing as I am new to programming, I'm not sure how effective my solution is. Basically I'm pulling in an email using Advanced Custom Fields, saving a spam-proofed version of it, then transforming it with javascript in the footer. FYI I am using Wordpress.

Here is the relevant part of the page:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<a href='' id='email'></a>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var email_storage = "nospam<?php the_field('team-email'); ?>";
  console.log(email_storage);
</script>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Then this script loads in the footer (after jQuery).

```
var email_length_nospam = email_storage.length;
var email = email_storage.substr(6,email_length_nospam);
var email_length = email.length;
var at = email.indexOf('@');
var email_name = email.substr(0,at);
var email_domain = email.substr((at+1),email_domain);
console.log(email_length_nospam,email);

jQuery('a#email').html(email_name+'@'+email_domain);
jQuery('a#email').attr('href','mailto:'+email);
```

My question is this:

Am I missing anything obvious? In other words, would a spam bot easily decode this due to an error on my part?

Comment: A bot that is running headless chrome can execute javascript and then search for `mailto`-links...

Comment: Thanks @LucaKiebel. Do you know a simple solution for this issue?

Comment: You cannot do much about bots scanning for emails (even non clickable images of the email do not help). And they often guess emails using dictionaries or combinations out of first and last name anyway. Personally I don't think it is worth to invest time to "protect" the email on the website, and I invested time in a robust spam protection strategy on the mailserver.

Comment: Providing an example would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

You could check the generated Javascript from [this](http://www.jottings.com/obfuscator/) email link obfuscator generator. For example, this is what gets generated if **info@example.com** is used for both email address and link text:

```
{ coded = "DMUm@WyBVJgW.AmV"
  key = "RGS5Amu4aKOHnZIix0TzqV8EBle1MQPDyhrkNfCp3gWXdjFbwvcosU9JY726Lt"
  shift=coded.length
  link=""
  for (i=0; i<coded.length; i++) {
    if (key.indexOf(coded.charAt(i))==-1) {
      ltr = coded.charAt(i)
      link += (ltr)
    }
    else {     
      ltr = (key.indexOf(coded.charAt(i))-shift+key.length) % key.length
      link += (key.charAt(ltr))
    }
  }
document.write("<a href='mailto:"+link+"'>info@example.com</a>")
}
```

I'm not sure how effective it is though.